# How to enable OGV in a powershell function

Tags: powershell, scripting

How to enable Out-GridView in a function.

I mean,

```
 "Hello" | Out-GridView
```

Works.

But if I have a simple function like this

```
function Count ([int]$times)
{
    for ($i=1; $i -le $times;$i++)
    {
        Write-Host $i
    }
}
```

Why calling `Count 5` doest not support a pipe to Out-GridView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `Write-Host` does not output to the pipeline at all.  It writes directly to the screen.  Replace `Write-Host` with `Write-Output` and it should work fine.

BTW, `Write-Output` is the default so you could just use:

```
function Count ([int]$times)
{
    for ($i=1; $i -le $times;$i++)
    {
        $i
    }
}
```

or even more simply:

```
function Count([int]$times) 
{
    1..$times
}
```